# different definition of connection on bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, riemannian-geometry

I have encountered two definitions of connection in two different setting namely in vector bundle and principal bundle and I don't see the equivalence in these two setting.

In vector bundle setting:
Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, $E$ be a vector bundle on it, and $TM$ be the tangent bundle of $M$.
Define a connection $\triangledown $ be a function from $\Gamma(TM,M) \times \Gamma(E,M) \rightarrow \Gamma(E,M)$. Here $\Gamma(-,M)$ is a functor from Vector bundle to its set of global section. So we can think of $\triangledown$ as a function from $\Gamma(E,M)$ to $\Omega^1(M)\otimes \Gamma(E,M)$. Here $\Omega^1(M)$ is the set of differential 1-from on $M$.

Let $\pi:P\rightarrow M$ be our principal $G$-bundle.
In principal $G$- bundle setting,
 we can think of connection as a set of subspace $H_p\subset T_pP$ which has dim equals to $\dim M$ or equivalently a connection form $\omega\in \Omega^1(M)\otimes \frak{g}$, where $\frak{g}$ is the lie algebra of the $G$.

I guess the definition of connection of principal $G$- bundle is more general since every vector bundle is equivalent to a principal $GL_n(\mathbb{F})$ (Here $\mathbb{F}$ can be $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$). Can someone explain to me that why these two definition are equivalent when $G=GL(n)$?

Thank you!

Comment: Your first definition is incomplete: you also need compatibility with the Leibniz rule and $\mathbb{R}$-linearity of the map. With that fixed, what you are looking for is that $\nabla = \partial + \omega$. That said, you seem to be identifying the vector bundle itself with a principal $GL(n)$ bundle; that is not the correct way. You should be identifying its frame field with a principal $GL(n)$ bundle. (A vector bundle by itself does not admit a global action of $GL(n)$, but its frame field does.)

Comment: Also, it is probably better to see both as different manifestations of the one answer to the question: how do you take derivatives when the fibers do not have canonical identifications? At the risk of some shameless self-promotion, some time ago I started [writing some notes](https://williewong.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/bundlesandderivatives.pdf) about this, but I never did quite finish. The portion that I did write may however help you recast your mental picture a bit. Basically, the correct motivating picture is that of a set of horizontal distributsion $H_p$. But in practice for...

Comment: ... computations the local representations in terms of Lie-algebra/vector valued one forms can be more convenient.

Comment: I see. Your explanation is helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us be a bit more careful. I will just expand a bit on Willie Wong's comments if you guys don't mind. Given a principal $G$-bundle $P$ on a base manifold $M$, and a linear representation space $V$ of $G$, with representation $\rho: G \to GL(V)$, where say the dimension of $V$ is $r$, there is a construction, called the associated fibre construction, which associates to $P$ and $\rho$ a vector bundle $E$ on the same base manifold $M$, of rank $r$ (the rank of a vector bundle is the dimension of each fibre).

On the other hand, given a fibre bundle $E$ on $M$ of rank $r$, its frame bundle is a principal $G$-bundle $P$ on $M$, where $G=GL(r,\mathbb{R})$. One can recover $E$ from $P$ by using the associated fibre bundle construction with representation $\rho: G \to GL(\mathbb{R}^r)$ being the identity map (remember, in this case, $G = GL(r,\mathbb{R})$).

So already, we see that principal bundles and vector bundles are not exactly equivalent (but are very closely related). It is similar to the following situation in representation theory. Given a representation $\rho: G \to GL(V)$, by just knowing the vector space $V$, one cannot a priori reconstruct $G$ and $\rho$ (all we know is that a homomorphic image of $G$ is a subgroup of $GL(V)$). However, in the case where $\rho$ is injective (faithful representation), so that $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $GL(V)$, one can often add extra structure to $V$, and recover $G$ as the group of all linear automorphisms of $V$ preserving that extra structure.

Let us now talk about connections. Given a connection on a vector bundle $E$, this gives the notion of parallel transport of frames of $E$ along curves in $M$. Thus, at a point $p \in M$, given a vector $v \in T_p(M)$, there is a well defined notion of a horizontal lift of $v$ to a tangent vector $\bar{v} \in T_{\bar{p}}(P)$, where $\bar{p}$ is a point in $P$ lying in the fibre over $p$ (in other words $\bar{p}$ represents a frame at $p$). This gives a choice of horizontal subspace at each point $\bar{p}$, which can be checked to yield a connection on $P$.

On the other hand, given a connection $\omega$ on a principal $G$-bundle $P$ over $M$, and a representation $\rho: G \to GL(V)$, there is an induced connection on the vector bundle $E$ associated to $P$ and $\rho$. Indeed, choose a local frame on $M$, which is basically a local section $s$ of the bundle map $P \to M$. Then $s^*(\omega)$ is a local $1$-form with values in the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. Composing then this $1$-form with the Lie algebra map $\rho_*: \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{gl}(r,\mathbb{R})$, gives a local $1$-form with values in $\mathfrak{gl}(r,\mathbb{R})$. One can then check that these local $1$-forms glue to give a global connection on $E$. I hope this helps.

Comment: I have a cleaner picture now. Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure about how to use parallel transport to get a lift of elements in tangent space. Would you mind explaining more?

Comment: Ben, you can think of it this way. If c(t) denotes a parametrized curve in the base manifold M, with c(0)=p, and if v_1,...,v_r is a frame of E_p at p, then by parallel transporting that initial frame, you get a frame v_1(t),...,v_r(t) along the curve c(t), which is the initial frame at t=0. But this parallel transported frame defines a parametrized curve \bar{c}(t) in P which is a lift of c(t). But then \frac{d\bar{c}}{dt} at t=0 is a horizontal lift of \frac{dc}{dt} at t=0.

Comment: The tangent bundle has a decomposition T_pP=T_pM+E_p and the horizontal subspace {H_p} defines a isomorphism between these two vector space. So I guess you meant by using parallel transport, we can  have a well-defined projection from T_pP to T_pM s.t. all parallel vectors are mapped to zero so we have a well-defined lift of v \in T_pM. Do I interpret it correctly? Thank you!

Comment: Yes Ben this is correct.